# Homemade ROM cartridge for Thomson TO7/70 home computer

Tags: thomson, rom, homemade

I recently acquired a [Thomson TO7/70](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_TO7/70) home computer. It came without any MEMO7 cartridges (ROM cartridges) that are necessary to properly use it. I found [images](http://dcmoto.free.fr/programmes/_html/support_memo7.html) of the ROMS, and a [schematic](http://dcmoto.free.fr/documentation/schemas/to770.html), so in principle it should be possible to make your own cartridge and program with the images.

Ideally I'd like something that can be easily programmed from a PC (maybe through serial or USB). One can still buy parallel EEPROMs, but I don't own an EEPROM programmer.

Has anyone every done something similar before? Maybe for a different computer? Any suggestions, tips, recommendations for parts?

Answer (score 9):

It's funny you should ask this now, Daniel (who runs the site you found the ROMs and schematic on) and Phil (another 8-bit enthusiast) recently produced an EEPROM-based PCB for exactly this purpose. You can find out more about it on [the system.cfg forum](http://forum.system-cfg.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=7086) (in French).

Daniel has many other [Thomson hardware projects](http://dcmoto.free.fr/bricolage/index.html), including [an SD card reader](http://dcmoto.free.fr/bricolage/sdmoto/index.html) and [associated controller](http://dcmoto.free.fr/bricolage/cs91-280/index.html) (which would allow you to use any [floppy-based Thomson software](http://dcmoto.free.fr/programmes/_html/support_to_fd.html)).

You can find cartridge-based systems which meet your requirements on other platforms; the [Atarimax Maxflash cartridge](http://www.atarimax.com/flashcart/documentation/) is one example for 8-bit Ataris.

Comment: Ah, nice find. Having someone else burn the EEPROM would solve the problem of the missing EEPROM programmer, yes. :-) Though I'd be still curious if something couldn't be made that I could program myself. Is there any information how the Maxflash cartridge works? I couldn't find any on the site.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to your project, you can use The [Mégarom T.2](https://megarom.forler.ch/en/), it's a MEMO7 Cartridge for Thomson T9000, TO7, TO7/70, TO8, TO8D, TO9, TO9+.
It contains 70 softwares.

Another way is to use the [SDDRIVE](http://dcmoto.free.fr/bricolage/sddrive/index.html) that is connected to the extension port of the TO7/70. It uses an SD card to emulate a floppy disk drive.